# Xamarin, Android: TextView's textcolor doenst change when set in xml AND programmatically

Tags: android, xamarin, android-text-color

feels like this is my first day of doing this:

No matter what I do:

```
        txtMotto.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor("#6f6e6e"));
```

or

```
            android:textColor="#765313"
```

The textcolor does not change AT ALL. However, my designer in Visual Studio does show the changed color, but my phone: NA.

It doenst matter what I change the textcolor to, it just doenst do anything...

How can this be?

Thanks

Comment: I guess to diagnose the problem, you could try to run it on an emulator or run it on a different phone. Just tested it on both the emulator and the phone, and the colour changes accordingly.

Comment: Wich android version have got you device?

Comment: Could you provide your other code? And does it work on other device or emulator?